# Why does the official XMLSchema.xsd fail to parse?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, schema, xsd-1.1

As an experiment, I want to create an XSD to Object Pascal. I am writing it in C# because I am more comfortable with it and it has a lot more tooling available for it.

I figured a good place to start is by using XSD.EXE to generate the equivalent Object Pascal data types from the official XSD of XMLSchema:

https://www.w3.org/2012/04/XMLSchema.xsd

I tried XSD.EXE as well as a bunch of other XSD to c# parsers. I made no changes to the XSD. None of the generators couldn't parse the XMLSchema.xsd.

Why is it failing?  What am I doing wrong?

```
joe$ wget https://www.w3.org/2012/04/XMLSchema.xsd
--2022-07-10 13:24:01--  https://www.w3.org/2012/04/XMLSchema.xsd
Resolving www.w3.org (www.w3.org)... 128.30.52.100
Connecting to www.w3.org (www.w3.org)|128.30.52.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 71264 (70K) [application/xml]
Saving to: ‘XMLSchema.xsd’

XMLSchema.xsd                    100%[=======================================================>]  69.59K  --.-KB/s    in 0.08s   

2022-07-10 13:24:01 (911 KB/s) - ‘XMLSchema.xsd’ saved [71264/71264]

joe$ xsd XMLSchema.xsd /c
Error: Invalid particle derivation by restriction. Invalid particle derivation by restriction.
Written file ./XMLSchema.cs
```

Comment: The XML ident header must be at first character in line 1.  The error message says it is on line 30.  You may have more than one ident line in the file.

Comment: This line is failing due to schema :  <xs:documentation>
    This type is extended by all types which allow annotation other than <schema> itself </xs:documentation>

Comment: Following is also wrong : <xs:documentation>
    This group is for the elements which can self-redefine (see <redefine> below).</xs:documentation>

Comment: Microsoft for sure only supports the version 1.0 of the W3C schema specification, I think the official schema for that is at https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd. Are you sure you are not trying to feed an XSD 1.1 schema to an XSD 1.0 parser/tool? From which specification document is https://www.w3.org/2012/04/XMLSchema.xsd linked as the official schema?

Comment: I'll check again, but I also tested it against several online xml validators. The XSD.exe I'm using is the latest version included with .NET 6.

Comment: You need to fix the two issue I listed above.  The file works when two items are corrected.  The Microsoft xsd.exe tool doesn't like the file.

Comment: Microsoft did never update its XML stack, so whether it is .NET 6 or ealier versions doesn't matter, in terms of the schema specification their tools support 1.0 but not 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema document at that location validates OK with the Saxon schema validator; I don't think there is anything wrong with it.

The error message seems very strange, because there is no XML declaration at line 30.

It feels to me as if you're not processing the document you think you are, but that's only because I can't think of any other explanation.

The schema you refer to is the schema for XSD 1.1, which the Microsoft schema processor doesn't support; but that doesn't account for the strange error message.

Comment: It appears the browser did something to the XSD file when I used it for downloading.  I did a direct wget from the URL and it generated the code, but gave me a different error. I updated my question.

Comment: I suggest you use the 1.0 version of the schema if you're using the Microsoft schema processor.

Comment: Thanks. What  will I miss if I downgrade to 1.0?  There must a reason for version upgrade. So even at .net 6, the Microbozos have yet to upgrade?

Comment: (a) XSD 1.1 has loads of good stuff, the most notable is assertions. (b) Microsoft hasn't updated their XML technologies to implement new W3C standards in 20 years. If you want the goodies, you need to use third party libraries (like Saxon - disclaimer, my product).

Comment: LOL!  It's been a while, but I contributed to libxml back in the 90s.

Comment: Sadly, libxml has also fallen behind in its support for newer XML technologies.

Comment: Is Saxon free for FOSS projects?

Comment: There is an open source version of Saxon (Saxon-HE) but it does not include XSD support.